# Typescript: How to generate and print an AST based on a data structure

Tags: typescript, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm starting a new project, and as part of its interface we have a whole bunch of "tokens", a recursive object with string values, like so:

```
const colors = {
  accent: '#f90',
  primary: {
    active: '#fff',
    inactive: 'silver'
  }
};
```

We offer a utility for using those through string-based path (e.g., `primary.active` for `#fff` in this case). Extracting all possible paths into an array is easy enough, but what we'd like to offer is better autocomplete for the consumers of this package, so rather than 'string', a union or enum of these possible paths. Does anybody maybe have experience with this? My initial approach would be to write a simple script that takes an array and prints it as a union using a template or some such, but given that we want to do this more often and our use-cases will increase in complexity, I think generating and printing an AST is maybe a better approach. I've written babel and recast codemods before, I'm just looking for some guidance with regards to existing toolsets, examples etc. I've done a quick Google but couldn't find anything. Ideally these will recompile along with my normal "watch" process, but that's a stretch-goal ^_^.

Comment: not sure it would help but check out https://ts-ast-viewer.com/

Comment: @lucascaro just to make sure I have your requirements right, you want to tramsform the `colors` object into a union type with all possible paths. For your example that would be `'accent' | 'primary.active' | 'primary.inactive'` ? And save it to a different file ?

Comment: @Steven Let me know if I can help with anything about my answer. It would be a shame for your bounty to go to waste without getting the answer you want :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir solutions works good, tested [demo source](https://github.com/vko-online/tsToAst)

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly 10x for testing :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can extract the object type and create the union types using the compiler API

```
import * as ts from 'typescript'
import * as fs from 'fs'

var cmd = ts.parseCommandLine(['test.ts']); // replace with target file
// Create the program
let program = ts.createProgram(cmd.fileNames, cmd.options);


type ObjectDictionary = { [key: string]: string | ObjectDictionary}
function extractAllObjects(program: ts.Program, file: ts.SourceFile): ObjectDictionary {
    let empty = ()=> {};
    // Dummy transformation context
    let context: ts.TransformationContext = {
        startLexicalEnvironment: empty,
        suspendLexicalEnvironment: empty,
        resumeLexicalEnvironment: empty,
        endLexicalEnvironment: ()=> [],
        getCompilerOptions: ()=> program.getCompilerOptions(),
        hoistFunctionDeclaration: empty,
        hoistVariableDeclaration: empty,
        readEmitHelpers: ()=>undefined,
        requestEmitHelper: empty,
        enableEmitNotification: empty,
        enableSubstitution: empty,
        isEmitNotificationEnabled: ()=> false,
        isSubstitutionEnabled: ()=> false,
        onEmitNode: empty,
        onSubstituteNode: (hint, node)=>node,
    };
    let typeChecker =  program.getTypeChecker();

    function extractObject(node: ts.ObjectLiteralExpression): ObjectDictionary {
        var result : ObjectDictionary = {};
        for(let propDeclaration of node.properties){            
            if(!ts.isPropertyAssignment( propDeclaration )) continue;
            const propName = propDeclaration.name.getText()
            if(!propName) continue;
            if(ts.isObjectLiteralExpression(propDeclaration.initializer)) {
                result[propName] = extractObject(propDeclaration.initializer);
            }else{
                result[propName] = propDeclaration.initializer.getFullText()
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    let foundVariables: ObjectDictionary = {};
    function visit(node: ts.Node, context: ts.TransformationContext): ts.Node {
        if(ts.isVariableDeclarationList(node)) {
            let triviaWidth = node.getLeadingTriviaWidth()
            let sourceText = node.getSourceFile().text;
            let trivia = sourceText.substr(node.getFullStart(), triviaWidth);
            if(trivia.indexOf("Generate_Union") != -1) // Will generate fro variables with a comment Generate_Union above them
            {
                for(let declaration of node.declarations) {
                    if(declaration.initializer && ts.isObjectLiteralExpression(declaration.initializer)){
                        foundVariables[declaration.name.getText()] = extractObject(declaration.initializer)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return ts.visitEachChild(node, child => visit(child, context), context);
    }
    ts.visitEachChild(file, child => visit(child, context), context);
    return foundVariables;
}



let result = extractAllObjects(program, program.getSourceFile("test.ts")!); // replace with file name 

function generateUnions(dic: ObjectDictionary) {
    function toPaths(dic: ObjectDictionary) : string[] {
        let result: string[] = []
        function extractPath(parent: string, object: ObjectDictionary) {
            for (const key of  Object.keys(object)) {
                let value = object[key]; 
                if(typeof value === "string") {
                    result.push(parent + key);
                }else{
                    extractPath(key + ".", value);
                }
            }
        }
        extractPath("", dic);
        return result;
    }

    return Object.entries(dic)
        .map(([name, values])=> 
        {
            let paths = toPaths(values as ObjectDictionary)
                .map(ts.createStringLiteral)
                .map(ts.createLiteralTypeNode);

            let unionType = ts.createUnionTypeNode(paths);
            return ts.createTypeAliasDeclaration(undefined, undefined, name + "Paths", undefined, unionType);
        })

}

var source = ts.createSourceFile("d.ts", "", ts.ScriptTarget.ES2015);
source = ts.updateSourceFileNode(source, generateUnions(result));

var printer = ts.createPrinter({ });
let r = printer.printFile(source);
fs.writeFileSync("union.ts", r);
```

Comment: Pretty interesting, but failed to test this, result is empty, here's [github repo](https://github.com/vko-online/tsToAst), what's wrong?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly looking into it now

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly There were two issues.
1. I did not know if your files will contain other declaration so to enable the generation a comment must appear above the variable /*Generate_Union*/
2. For exported variables, this comment is not found directly on the variable list but rather on the parent, and so it was not getting picked up. Fixed it to check for the comment directly on the node or on the parent node.
If you want to generate for all variables in the input file just remove the if
`if(hasTrivia(node) || hasTrivia(node.parent))`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Created a PR with the changes https://github.com/vko-online/tsToAst/pull/1

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can accomplish what you want with a combination of enums and interfaces/types:

````
``` 
export enum COLORS {
    accent = '#f90',
    primary_active = '#fff',
    primary_inactive = 'silver',
}

interface ICOLORS {
    [COLORS.accent]: COLORS.accent,
    [COLORS.primary_active]: COLORS.primary_active,
    [COLORS.primary_inactive]: COLORS.primary_inactive
}

export type COLOR_OPTIONS = keyof ICOLORS;

export type PRIMARY_COLOR_OPTIONS = keyof Pick<ICOLORS, COLORS.primary_active | COLORS.primary_inactive>;

export function setColor (color: PRIMARY_COLOR_OPTIONS): void {}

// elsewhere:

import {COLORS, setColor} from 'somewhere';

setColor(COLORS.primary_inactive); // works

setColor(COLORS.accent); //error

```
````

Comment: I think my question was maybe not clear enough; what I'm looking for is tooling to generate typescript code incrementally (as in: during development), to go from my original data-structure (nested object), to a union:

    `type Color = 'accent' | 'primary.active';`

I fully understand how to extract the object and its keys through an AST parser, what I'm unsure of is how to construct typescript based on this array of strings.